# Tableau Trusted authentication not working

Tags: tableau-api

We are trying to enable trusted authentication in our server so that we can embed our dashboards in our web pages without additional authentication.
We followed the steps below to enable the same

1. We added the Server IP Address and Host name in Tableau Trusted Authentication
2. Using /trusted API, We generated the token for my username.
3. Using that token, Application displays Tableau views in web page as Embedded Widget.

At first time of rendering, It is working as expected. After refreshing the page, It shows below error for same token.

"Could not locate unexpired trusted ticket 
Click the Refresh button in your web browser and try again.
If you continue to receive this error please contact your Tableau Server Administrator."

How to solve this issue

Comment: Did you check the following link https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/error-could-not-locate-unexpired-trusted-ticket